# how can i call a method while the canvas is pressed

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game with a vehicle and I want to move this vehicle while the canvas is pressed something like this but that doesn't work.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < 150 && event.getY() > 550 && event.getY() < 700) {

           do{

              System.out.println("Hallo");

              }while (canvas.isPressed());

        return false;
```

but I just get this output:

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
I/System.out: Hallo
```

any idea?

Comment: add your vehicle class code

Comment: Did you try with event.getPressure() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in `onTouch` or `onTouchEvent` like so:

```java
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    // Player has touched the screen
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    System.out.println("Hallo");

                    break;

                    // Player has removed finger from screen
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a global boolean to know when the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event is received.

```
   mUserTouched = true; // Set to true when MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
   mUserTouched = false; // set to false when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is received
```

You'll then probably want to use a `Timer` or some other looper that will start up initially whenever MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is received. And have it fire off calls to `invalidate()` based on some interval. `invalidate()` will cause `View.onDraw()` to be called so you can redraw your car's positions. When MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is received, cancel the `Timer`

If there are bounds than you will also need to set `mUserTouched = false'` whenever the `MotionEvent` occurs outside of your bounds.